# How to call constructor of a template base class in a template derived class?

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a base template class Array:

```
template <class T = Point> class Array{
    protected:
        T* m_data;
        int size;
    public:
        Array();    // constructor
        Array(int n);   // constructor
        Array(const Array<T>& s_data);  //Copy Constructor
        // and so on..
}
```

And it has constructors and destructors. Also I have a derived template class NumericArray:

```
template <class T = int> 
class NumericArray:public Array<T>{

    public:
        NumericArray();
        NumericArray(int n);
        NumericArray(const NumericArray<T>& s_data);

        ~NumericArray();    //destructor

};
```

Since I need to initialize the private members in the base class so I need to call the base constructors in the derived constructors. But how? I tried

```
template <class T>
NumericArray<T>::NumericArray(int n){
    Array<T>(n);  // it will think I create a Array<T> names n
}

template <class T>
NumericArray<T>::NumericArray(int n):Array(n){
    // No field in NumericalArray called Array
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Why you did not try 2 other variants, just curious?

Comment: @Slava I did. Just post this one as an example.

Comment: If you did you would hit the correct way

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Combine your solutions, use the initializer list and the full name:

```
NumericArray<T>::NumericArray(int n)
 : Array<T>(n)
{

}
```

Also, since they become a dependent name, fields of Array have to be accessed like this:

```
Array<T>::m_data; // inside a NumericArray method
```

Also, if it's not some experiment or homework, please use std::vector instead of pointer and size.

Comment: That's ... amazing. I think I tried this one before(and failed) but this time it is working.

Answer (score 0):

My 5 cents.

Suppose parent class is in namespace, you need to call it like this:
(it took me 15 min to figure it out)

```
namespace detail{

    template<typename T>
    struct A{
        A(int){
            
        }
    };

}

template<typename T>
struct B : detail::A<T>{
    B(int i) : detail::A<T>(i){

    }
};

int main(){
    B<char> x(4);
}
```