# C++ derived template class is inheriting from template base class, cannot call base class constructor

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, constructor

i am trying to inherit from base class which is template, the derived class is also template, they have same type T. I am getting compile error: illegal member initialization: 'Base' is not a base or member...

Why? How can i call the base class constructor?

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Base {
public:
    Base(T a) {
        std::cout << "A: " << a << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class T>
class Derived : public Base<T> {
public:
    Derived(T a) :
        Base(a) // this is the problem
    {}
};

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    Derived<int> derived(a);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call constructor of a template base class in a template derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064515/how-to-call-constructor-of-a-template-base-class-in-a-template-derived-class)

Answer (score 5):

Since `Base` is a template, you need to specify the template parameter in the member initializer list:

```
Derived(T a) : Base<T>(a) {}
                // ^^^
```